# A Problem on Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all entire function $f$ such that $\vert f^{'}(z)\vert\leq M(1+\sqrt{\vert z\vert})$, for $M>0$.

I did as follows:
Let $f^{'}(z)=F(z)=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nz^{n}$, $a_n=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\vert z\vert=1}\dfrac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$. Thus $\vert a_n\vert \leq\dfrac{M(1+\sqrt{R})}{R^n}$. Thus as $R \to \infty$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus $F(z)=a_0$. Hence $f(z)=a_0+bz$. Am I right?

Comment: I think this is a proper proof.

Answer (score 1):

Easier -

$f$ is entire, so, $f'$ is too. By the "Extended" Liouville's Theorem, $f'$ must be a polynomial of degree no more than 1. But then again using the condition, $f'$ must be a constant polynomial. so $f$ is a linear polynomial.